# HttpStatus 415 when putting form and multipart file in java spring app

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a form and a multipart file to server. This is my spring controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/prfimg", method=RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "content-type=multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Secured(Privileges.CAN_USER_WRITE)
    public void milanUpdate(@Valid @RequestBody User resource, 
                            @RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file){

        RestPreconditions.checkRequestElementNotNull(resource);
        RestPreconditions.checkRequestElementNotNull(file);

        resource.setPhoto(file.getOriginalFilename());
        userServiceImpl.updateUserWithPicture(resource, file);
    }
```

However, when i do send data via a valid url, i get this response :

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f89e9e35dd0> 
{ URL: ***request-url***/prfimg } 
{ status code: 415, headers {
    Accept = "application/hal+json, application/octet-stream, text/plain;charset=UTF-8, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1, application/xml, text/xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/*+xml, multipart/form-data, application/json;charset=UTF-8, application/*+json;charset=UTF-8, */*";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "***home site page***";
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" = "X-Requested-With, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type";
    "Access-Control-Max-Age" = 3600;
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Thu, 04 Aug 2016 13:12:24 GMT";
    Expires = 0;
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains";
    "X-Application-Context" = application;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = DENY;
    "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} })
```

JSON for the user object and the multipart file are valid.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: File uploading is only supported for POST requests, other types aren't supported.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaa ! I'm stupid ! Thanks.